# Rails get last X objects with attribute match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `DeferredHost`, which also has an attribute `ignore_flag`.  At the present, I'm just getting all of the deferred hosts in my controller:

`@deferred_hosts = @company.deferred_hosts.last(5)`

However, I'd like to make it subjective and only get the last 5 deferred hosts that have the `ignore_flag = true`.

How can I go about doing this?  Should I use an if statement and loop through each deferred host, or is there a more 'Rails' way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where` to make the query more specific:

```
@deferred_hosts = @company.deferred_hosts.where(ignore_flag: true).last(5)
```